# Confusion with string#concat(integer) method's output

Tags: ruby

I was playing around to test the `String#concat(integer)` method. The code is as follows:

```
irb(main):006:0> a="hello"
=> "hello"
irb(main):008:0> a<< "world"
=> "helloworld"
irb(main):009:0> a.concat(33)
=> "helloworld!"
irb(main):010:0> a.concat(32)
=> "helloworld! "
irb(main):011:0> a.concat(31)
=> "helloworld! \x1F"
irb(main):012:0> a.concat(34)
=> "helloworld! \x1F\""
irb(main):013:0> a.concat(3)
=> "helloworld! \x1F\"\x03"
irb(main):014:0>
```

But couldn't understand—why does `33` value give the `helloworld!` output (correctly, but not the other integers)?

Why/How does 32 give the output `"helloworld! "`?

In what way `a << "world"` made the string internally?

Comment: Ascii 33  is ! 32 is a space ???

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-concat) says: `If the object is a Integer, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation.` Perhaps "codepoint" confuses you, so read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point and http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/

Comment: @theTinMan thank you sir, i will,but the third link is too much! :(

Comment: @theTinMan just asking one suggestion, in the docs there are some modules where not a single code mentioned,some of the methods has also no description. as a beginner how should i start to test them to see hows they work - any idea? as an example [ENV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ENV.html#method-c-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you `helloworld!` because ASCII code for `!` mark is 33.
[Link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.IBMDS.doc_6.1/install29.htm).